# Automatically apply external script whenever image changes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, photoshop-scripting, raster, krita

While editing an image (i.e. while there's a new version of it every few seconds), I would like to continuously see what the newest version would look like after running an external script on it (for example dithering by ImageMagick).

One possible solution is this:

- Use an image editor that can auto-save the image after every change ([here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/138624/)'s how to do this in Photoshop for example)
- Write a program that runs the external script and displays its result whenever autosaves happen (i.e. whenever the file changes)

Is there a more straightforward solution to integrate the external script into my workflow? Maybe GIMP or Photoshop allow using the external script "as an [adjustment layer](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/adjustment-fill-layers.html)" (i.e. non-destructive editing) or so? (Is that even possible? [Maybe in Photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/138611/); [not in Krita](https://docs.krita.org/en/reference_manual/layers_and_masks/filter_layers.html#index-0:%7E:text=not%20supported); [GIMP doesn't even have built-in non-destructive editing](https://discuss.pixls.us/t/adjustment-layers-in-gimp/9148/2))

Comment: Illustrator can be set up to do this everytime you activate the window so presumsbly photoshop can too

Comment: @joojaa What is that feature of Illustrator called?

Comment: In Photoshop something similar is possible using its _Generator_ functionality: it has `imageChanged` event: the same tech powers Photoshop `Generate Image Assets` function. I think it'd be easier to answer your question if you'd provided an example of what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Its in file handling its called update links set it to automatic.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy There's an example in the question: dithering by ImageMagick. Is some info still lacking?

Comment: @root for that you need to know what dithering does in Image Magic: maybe some screens could be useful. For instance I know there's a setup for creating dithered graphics in Photoshop: http://www.danfessler.com/blog/hd-index-painting-in-photoshop. On the other hand the answer also depends if the dithering is an example and you want to be able to get any custom results

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy [Your link](http://www.danfessler.com/blog/hd-index-painting-in-photoshop) is cool, but it sounds like it's for a combination of several one-dimensional palettes ("You can't color sample between ramps" etc.) rather than any mixes of any colors (which is what I want). I'll be happy with something like [8x8 ordered dither from ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#ordered-dither) specifically, or with running any custom external script in general.