# Make an own adjustment layer in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, photoshop-effects, photoshop-scripting, imagemagick

How can I program my own [adjustment layer](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/adjustment-fill-layers.html) (i.e. non-destructive editing step) in Photoshop?

For example in order to run dithering by ImageMagick as a non-destructive editing step within the stack of layers.

Comment: btw, in Krita, [non-destructive](https://docs.krita.org/en/user_manual/layers_and_masks.html#layers-and-masks) editing [natively can't be external](https://docs.krita.org/en/reference_manual/layers_and_masks/filter_layers.html): "Unlike applying a filter directly on to a section of a Paint Layer, Filter Layers do not actually alter the original image in the Paint Layers below them. Once again, non-destructive editing!" but "Only Krita native filters (the ones in the Filters menu) can be used with Filter Layers. Filter Layers are not supported using the externally integrated G’Mic filters."

Comment: Unfortunately you can't add custom Adjustment Layers to Photoshop, there's no API for that. You can create custom filters with C++: maybe it'd possible to apply them to smart objects, edit the content of that SO and have some sort of interactivity. You can also connect external apps to PS via TCP, so you can send pixeldata from PS to your app that can do all the calculations and show the preview. I don't know a lot of information about all this so can't really share any useful links, sorry