# Photoshop auto-save as PNG

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, file-management

How can I make Photoshop automatically save the image as PNG in the background whenever I make any changes in Photoshop (brush strokes etc.)?

Comment: [File > Generate > Image Assets](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html)

Comment: Are you trying to create an animation?

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy I want to save after every action (brush stroke etc.) automatically, without pressing Ctrl+S or anything

Comment: @AndrewH No, I want another program to be aware of what I'm doing in Photoshop and always have the newest version of the image. I can make that other program track file changes.

Comment: @root have you tried `Image Assets`? It does exactly what you're saying.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy I can't test it right now and the documentation is unclear regarding automatic updates, but [here](https://youtu.be/AbgT7unfSaU?t=335) it looks correct. Will you post `Image Assets` as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a `Generate Image Assets` feature: it uses a node-powered `Generator` inside Photoshop to quickly export images after each change. Simply put your layers to a group with a name like `my_image.png`, enable the plugin from `File > Generate > Image Assets` menu and you'll have your png in a subfolder of the location of your saved `.psd` file.

More info on [Adobe website](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html).

Here's a video where you can see a file change on the fly during changes: https://youtu.be/AbgT7unfSaU?t=335