# Krita auto-save as PNG

Tags: save, krita, file-management

Photoshop has the feauture ["Generate Image Assets"](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html) that can [automatically save PNG files upon every action (brush stroke etc.)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/138624/).

Can Krita save the image as PNG automatically after each change?

[Krita Batch Exporter](https://github.com/GDQuest/krita-batch-exporter) comes close to this, but [seems to require pressing a button every time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJE5iqE8Q7c).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used the batch exporter but do you have the ability to change the hotkey if you do than you might be able to change it to activate whenever you lift your pen from your tablet or let go of your left mouse button. that way when you're finished with your stroke it triggers the addon to save an image.